# Argument Exception: Empty path not allowed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, argumentexception

I want to access the `.txt` file inside a Resources folder by the following code

```
void Start () {
    TextAsset txtAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("Dialogue0", typeof(TextAsset));
    string dialogue = txtAsset.text;

    lines = new List<DialogueLine>();

    LoadDialogue(dialogue);
} 

void LoadDialogue(string filename)
{
    string line;
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filename);

    using (r)
    {
        do
        {
            line = r.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                string[] lineData = line.Split('|');
                if (lineData[0] == "Player")
                {
                    DialogueLine lineEntry = new DialogueLine(lineData[0], "", 0,0, "");
                    lineEntry.options = new string[lineData.Length - 1];
                    for (int i = 1; i < lineData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        lineEntry.options[i - 1] = lineData[i];
                    }
                    lines.Add(lineEntry);
                }
                else
                {
                    DialogueLine lineEntry = new DialogueLine(lineData[0], lineData[1], int.Parse(lineData[2]), int.Parse(lineData[3]), lineData[4]);
                    lines.Add(lineEntry);
                }
            }
        }
        while (line != null);
        r.Close();
    }
}
```

but an error always occurs saying:

```
ArgumentException: Empty path not allowed

System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, 
            Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize) 
(at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs:159)

System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (string)

DialogueParser.LoadDialogue (System.String filename) (at Assets/Script/DialogueParser.cs:54)

DialogueParser.Start () (at Assets/Script/DialogueParser.cs:44)
```

[The .txt file is really exist, named "Dialogue0.txt"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tlfP.png)

I've been searching for a while now but I haven't seen a solution in my problem.

EDIT: [Contents of dialogue0.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGLVU.png)

Comment: Do you confirm your string dialogue = txtAsset.text; is correct? Because dialogue will used as filename.

Comment: Check the content in "Dialogue0.txt" ,Does it has empty line?

Comment: @RonTang there are no empty line in "Dialogue0.txt" but it has contents. Also, I tried to print "dialogue" and it's empty. The only thing that's showing is "UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)"

Answer (score 0):

The content of "Dialogue0.txt" will be used as filename. So please check the the content of  Dialogue0.txt. Print "dialogue" find what happen. Maybe at last has an empty line.

**update:**

This maybe an issue of unity. You can read [TextAsset.text is "" although the file does have content](https://forum.unity.com/threads/textasset-text-is-although-the-file-does-have-content.501846/) for more detail.

[If your Dialogue0.txt contain slanted apostrophe , Changing this to a regular vertical apostrophe (ascii 0x27) make the file load correctly!](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1425195/resourcesload-wont-read-text-file.html)

For other situation,you could try this or change unity version.

```
 string content = lang.text;
 if(content == "")
 content = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(lang.bytes);
```

Comment: I tried to print "dialogue" and it's empty. The only thing that's showing is "UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object). Although, it has contents but there's no empty line

Comment: I know what my problem is now. StreamReader reads the contents as filename because the ".text" in TextAssets is already reads the contents of my "Dialogue0.txt" file therefore I need some major changes in my code. I searched that TextAssets and StreamReader shouldn't go with each other because they're both a read/write codes. Although, I still have issue because after the first line, the second line isn't showing. Anyways, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have the extension "Dialogue0.txt" instead of just "Dialogue0":

```
TextAsset txtAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("Dialogue0.txt", typeof(TextAsset));
```

Comment: I tried that a lot of times but it giving me an error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

You can always print out all resources to check it out from API level.

> var allResources = Resources.LoadAll("[PathRelativeToResourcesDir]")